# Javascript: Replace Element vs Change Element Property

Tags: javascript, dom

While reading an [Image Lazy Loading](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/) script, I noticed that there are such operations(comments added by me):

```
function loadImage (el) {
    var img = new Image()
      , src = el.getAttribute('data-src');
    img.onload = function() {
      if (!! el.parent)
        el.parent.replaceChild(img, el) // Replace Element
      else
        el.src = src; // Change Element Property
    }
    img.src = src;
  }
```

Why does not it simply Change Element Property? It is much simpler. Why create a new element and replace the old element (both elements are images,anyway)? What are the advantages?

```
function loadImage (el) {
    src = el.getAttribute('data-src');
    el.src = src; // Change Element Property
  }
```

Comment: The script contains some odd things like using `el.parent` instead of `el.parentNode`, or using `!!el.parent` instead of just `el.parent`, so it probably shouldn't be considered an ultimate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably done this way to provide off-screen loading and for browser efficiency purposes (though the specific implementation is flawed in this regard).

It seems likely that the lazy loading wants the actual loading of the image to happen "out of view".  So, for that reason, a new Image object is created and the `.src` is set on that.

Then, once that new image has been loaded, it is more efficient for the browser to actually use that new image object rather than change the `.src` on the image that is in the DOM.  So, if the image appears to be in at least a DOM fragment (e.g. if it has a parent), then the new image is swapped into its place and the only thing the browser has to do is a DOM operation and then a repaint.

If the image has no parent, then there is no way to swap out the original, so it just sets the `.src` on it.  Setting the `.src` property will cause the browser to request the image URL again.  It will find that URL in a local cache, but it will still have to get the image from the cache and parse the image format (which is more work than just swapping the DOM element).

---

It also appears that the reference to `el.parent` in the code should be `el.parentNode`.  If I go to the lazyloading demo page and set a breakpoint in their own code, it never does the `.replaceChild()` option of the `if` statement because `el.parent` is not a standard DOM property and is thus always `undefined` in the browsers I tried - Chrome, Firefox, IE11 and Edge.

Comment: `Then, once that new image has been loaded, it is more efficient for the browser to actually use that new image object rather than change the .src on the image that is in the DOM.` But I do not think this is efficient at all. You still have to wait and load the image, then swap. While `Setting the .src property` ,you just have to wait and load, you do not have to swap. The latter is more efficient.

Comment: @J.Joe - If you want off-screen loading, you can't just set the `.src` property of the original DOM element immediately. Instead, the loading or caching of the image is done in a different DOM element that is not visible.  Then, once the image is now in the browser cache, then it can be displayed and that's where you have the choice of swapping in the first DOM element or loading the .src in an element. So, the efficiency argument assumes you want off-screen loading. If you don't want off-screen loading, then yes you could just set the `.src` on the original image and never create a new image.

Comment: Note that replacing an element leads to losing event handlers that the original element could potentially have. So I would prefer just to change `src` of the existing element once the image is preloaded offscreen.

Comment: @MaratTanalin - Good point.  As it turns out, due to a coding mistake in the lazy loading code, it actually never does the `.replaceChild()` and always just does an assignment to `.src`.